# Sending Email in Android Studio App using JavaMail API: Bug in server connecting code

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I recently used the code of the first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for an app. To make it less hardcoded I made an EditText widget in Android Studio for the sender email address (and password) and extracted the information from it in my OnClick function by these two lines of code:

```
et_email_from = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et_email_from);
final String user = et_email_from.getText().toString();
```

The problem is that once I click the button and the sendMail function is called, I can't change the sender address anymore. I mean I can, but the app will still send it from the first sender email address. Can someone show me how I can solve this problem? I think it has something to do with where in the code the connection is made with the server, but I'm new to coding in Java and I don't know where to find this code.

Comment: Hi @ruben-troch , your problem is you are making your variable as final. Check my answer below it will help you

Comment: The code you copied is full of these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Try correcting them and see if it works better.  Make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).  Also, you don't need your own ByteArrayDataSource; [there's one in JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `String user` as `non-final`.

in place of   `final String user = et_email_from.getText().toString();  //Dont use as final`

use `String user = et_email_from.getText().toString(); //use like this`

then you will be able to send to different-different email (multiple users) Programatically.

Comment: But then I get the error: Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final. I think this is because I make use of the variables inside a new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(). I solved the problem now by assigning the variables inside the AsyncTask. I don't know if this is a good solution, but it works for now.